# VScode extesion for be able to see the console.log value write in IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code, console.log

I look for VScode extension to be able to see the console.log values write in IDE.
It looks like this:

[image]

I have tried quokka but there is a pro version requiered to be able to work with existing file on save.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest and most popular:  https://quokkajs.com
there's another similar project  https://wallabyjs.com/, but that is primarily for tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I installed and tried to run this extension and realized that this functionality only works for new files created through the extension interface, it requires a premium version to work on existing files. Any chance there are other extensions that provide the same functionality for free?

Comment: Try RunJS, I have not tried it yet, but it seems to do the job.

Comment: But are you sure you need pro version for working with recent files? As in their docs https://quokkajs.com/pro/ recent files are included in free version.

Comment: I have edit the post with a screenshot, check it out

Comment: It's not the best solution, but you can click "new typescript file" and copy the code into it.